# ncurses printw bug when embedded in double for loop, c++

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am making a simple game in c++ that outputs to the console. Im using printw for this with ncurses. To print the grid, I have a for loop as follows:

```
for (int j; j < height + 2; j ++){
    for (int i; i<width+2; i++){
        printw("#");
    }
    printw("\n");
}
```

The output of this is just one line of #'s. At first I thought maybe it had something to do with the variable height, so I replaced it with its value, 22. Same, failed result. Then I physically typed out two for loops like this:

```
for (int i; i<width+2; i++){
    printw("#");
}
printw("\n");
for (int i; i<width+2; i++){
    printw("#");
}
```

and I got two lines of #'s! Really weird bug. I also tried while loops, but I had the same failed result. I'm new to c++, I come from python, so I could be missing something super obvious here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: On Stack Overflow, we generally don't edit "SOLVED" into questions; accepting answers automatically marks it as "solved" by changing the colour showed in question listings etc. It's fine -- that's not written in the [tour] -- but I'm just letting you know.

Comment: thanks. i didnt know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not initialising your variables to `0`, so they could be anything! Rewrite it like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < height + 2; j ++){
    for (int i = 0; i<width+2; i++){
        printw("#");
    }
    printw("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, a `for` loop is used for iterating over a sequence (that is either a list, a tuple or a string). This is less like the `for` keyword in other programming language, and works more like an `iterator` method as found in other object-orientated programming languages.

The traditional `for` loop in C++ is different from Python's. (There is a version of `for` which is called range-based `for` introduced in C++11 which is similar to Python's.)

In C++, you have to initialize the variables declared in the `for` loop before using them, otherwise the behaviour would be unexpected.